# Why it happen error that could not find user happen when I destroy user from grouping table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

all I'm new be to rails.
I want to destroy  user that have group_id in grouping table.

My source code is here.

GroupsController

```
def leave
  @user = current_user
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @user.groupings.find_by_group_id(@group).destroy
  redirect_to :back , notice: "Destroy!"
end
```

lists.html.haml

```
 %td= link_to("Destroy",leave_group_path(:id => group),:confirm => "Are you       sure",:method => :delete)
```

When I click "Destroy" button , then it happen error that `Couldn't find User with id=1`
I want to destroy only grouping table, but why can't find current_user.I don't remove current_user.

Error logs is that

```
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `current_user'
```

And current_user is provided helper_method of OmniAuth Plugin.

current_user is implemented following this ..

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Please some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it definitely hitting that controller action? What line does the backtrace show the error is occuring at? Are there any before filters on the groups controller?

Comment: What does the current_user method look like and/or what auto system are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I've update my question content to add 'error logs' and current_user method. Please see this.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error that says `could not find user with id=1` then there is not user with id=1.
Ofte we delete/destroy the user.

In rails when you **destroy the record with id = 1** and create another record then the newly created records **id will not be 1**. This could have happened the case with you.

Also, your association in models is this, i am guessing ::

User Model

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

`has_many :groups` # not **groupings**

`end`

Group model       #as mentioned in the question.

`class Group < ActiveRecord::Base`

`belongs_to :user`

`end`

This means ::

`@user.groupings.find_by_group_id(@group).destroy` could not possible be correct.

Instead try this ::

`@user.groups.find_by_group_id(@group).destroy`

Since, a user has_many groups and not groupings.

[Read More about naming conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)

Comment: Thanks asking for my question. but grouping is intermediate table. so user.rb `has_many :groups , :through => :groupings`, group.rb `has_many :through => :groupings`, and  attend action which inverse of  delete action is  like this...`@user.groupings.create!(:group_id => group)`